# Find all words without figures using RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I found this code to get all words of a string,

```
static string[] GetWords(string input)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[\w']*\b");

    var words = from m in matches.Cast<Match>()
                where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value)
                select TrimSuffix(m.Value);

    return words.ToArray();
}

static string TrimSuffix(string word)
{
    int apostrapheLocation = word.IndexOf('\'');
    if (apostrapheLocation != -1)
    {
        word = word.Substring(0, apostrapheLocation);
    }

    return word;
}
```

1. Please describe about the code.
2. How can I get words without figures?

Comment: English correction: You probably mean: please describe what the code does and/or how it works. "describe about" is ungrammatical and overly vague.

Comment: @Robin Green Thanks , I'm new in English language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"\b[\w']*\b");
```

the code is using a regex that will look for any word; \b means border of word and \w is the alpha numerical POSIX class to get everything as letters(with or without graphical accents), numbers and sometimes underscore and the ' is just included in the list along with the alphaNum. So basically that is searching for the begining and the end of the word and selecting it.

then

```
var words = from m in matches.Cast<Match>()
                    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value)
                    select TrimSuffix(m.Value);
```

is a LINQ syntax, where you can do SQL-Like queries inside your code. That code is getting every match from the regex and checking to see if the value is not empty and to get it without spaces. Its also where you can add your figure validation.

and This:

```
static string TrimSuffix(string word)
    {
        int apostrapheLocation = word.IndexOf('\'');
        if (apostrapheLocation != -1)
        {
            word = word.Substring(0, apostrapheLocation);
        }

        return word;
    }
```

is removing the ' of the words who have it and getting just the part that is before it

*i.e.* for **don't** word it will get only the **don**

Answer (score 3):

> 2 How can I get words without figures?

You'll have to replace `\w` with `[A-Za-z]`

So that your RegEx becomes `@"\b[A-Za-z']*\b"`

And then you'll have to think about TrimSuffix(). The regEx allows apostrophes but TrimSuffix() will extract only the left part. So  "it's" will become "it".

Comment: Well said but something is wrong because:
I wrote 8zfa+2t^4/13hs-2
I thought the result with this RegEx should be : zfa , t , hs

Comment: shaahin, you now run into problems with \b not including digits. Maybe just drop that and only look for "[A-Za-z']*"